# How to add multiline text in varchar(MAX) field

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms

I have created varchar(MAX) field as memo field. Unfortunately I do not find a way how to add multiline text into such field using MS SQL Server Management Studio. If I use copy/paste of multiline text only first line of multiline test is inserted into varchar(MAX) field.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you observe, if you paste in multi-line text only the first line is inserted, instead paste the text into an update statement and run that;

```
update T set fld =
'aaa
sss
ddd'
where ...
```

(You need to `SELECT` in *results to text* mode to observe the lines, in the grid view they appear as double-spaces)

Comment: May i know how to select it as multiple rows

Comment: Best to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `REPLACE('Line1@Line2@Line3', '@', CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ALT+ENTER.. this should add a new line

Comment: All+Enter jums to next records.